# Android RTSP streaming failing

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, wowza

I 've Set up wowza streaming server in my ubuntu box for RTSP streaming video files. The video gets stream perfectly when I 've Totem video player at client side. The same url or video is failing to work on android device and the application that tries to access that rtsp url breaks with Mediaplayer error (1,-1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently also set up a Wowza streaming server, and had three things trip me up before I could get it to work. One or more of these may help you out.

Wowza Settings:

1) In the Vhost.xml file, make sure that `<port>1935</port>` is changed to `<port> 1935,554 </port>` (You may have to use ROOT to start the Wowza server after this. 554 is a reserved port for RTSP streaming).

2) In the Application.xml file make sure PlayMethod is set like this:  `<PlayMethod>none</PlayMethod>`

In your Android Code:

3) In your Android code, the URL needs to follow the format `rtsp://serverip/live/myStream.sdp`

so NO port number in the URL. This is the one that tripped me up the longest.

After this, I was able to play my video by passing the url right to the MediaPlayer.

Comment: Thanks Aurora.. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: .
Now Its working Aurora.. But I 've encountered one issue regarding the quality of video that sometimes get lowered while playing it into android phone.

Comment: I think you are going to have to look at the actual video itself and make sure that it is small enough for mobile, and maybe allow a few frames to drop here and there. Remember 3G networks can be a bit slow compared to wifi. If you've got the video showing on the device, you have fixed your problem - now you need to get appropriately formatted video. And that I can't answer - I was provided with my video, and just worry about the code end.

Comment: the <PlayMethod> is the one inside RTP/Authentication, right?

Comment: @Aurora- I had this exact problem and for that i followed your solution, but still get it to Broadcast successfully. Can you provide any suggestion as what else can be hindering factor ?

Comment: @Aurora- I am having the same problem and followed your solution, still audio file "myStream.sdp.mp4/myStream.sdp" saved under content folder..please suggest for the same.

Comment: I'm afraid that the problems that I had are now so far in the past for me that I cannot provide any additional advice - Good luck.